# How can I remove HTML content attributes in Java?

Tags: regex

I want to remove from my regex all content for my attributes. Below I have my regular expression and I want to happen is to, for example, I have this: style=" padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" this is an HTML attribute and I want to remove what's inside the "" which is the content. So from style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" I want to be only style="" and from class="MsoNormal I want only class="" and from style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly" I want only style="" and last attribute span style="font-family:"Open Sans",sans serif;color:#444444" in style = "";

Can I do this with regex? I'm using Java.

```
regexpStart = '(?<=Name:<o:p></o:p></span></p>###LB###</td>###LB###<td 
   style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">###LB##';
regexpStart += '#<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line- 
   height-rule:exactly"><span style="fon';
regexpStart += 't-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans serif;color:#444444">)'; 
   regexpEnd = '(?=<o:p>)';
   regexp = regexpStart + '.*?' + regexpEnd;
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using for your regular expression?  Note that parsing HTML with regex generally is not advisable.

Comment: I'm using Java.

Comment: Please include the content you want to handle here.  If you have nested HTML, then I won't give you a regex solution.

Comment: What is the target this regex is supposed to work on ?

Comment: The target is an HTML Email which I'm sending from Outlook and I'm storing all the content from Email in a variable, and that variable is the target.
p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
m = p.matcher(html);

Comment: I was hoping to see an HTML snippet from the email you are trying to match.

Comment: I posted now the HTML source from where I'm trying to fetch the name. ###LB### it's just a replacement for \n. In my source file just look for this part: Name:<o:p></o:p></span></p and you will see what I am trying to do with my regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This is the source which is stored in html variable from where I'm fetching and parsing the name:

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:"Cambria Math";
 panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"Open Sans";
 panose-1:2 11 6 6 3 5 4 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin:0cm;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:blue;
 text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:purple;
 text-decoration:underline;}
p
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.msonormal0, li.msonormal0, div.msonormal0
 {mso-style-name:msonormal;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.readmsgbody, li.readmsgbody, div.readmsgbody
 {mso-style-name:readmsgbody;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.externalclass, li.externalclass, div.externalclass
 {mso-style-name:externalclass;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.bg-gray, li.bg-gray, div.bg-gray
 {mso-style-name:bg-gray;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 background:#EEEEEE;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.code, li.code, div.code
 {mso-style-name:code;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 background:#EEEEEE;
 word-break:break-all;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.social-link, li.social-link, div.social-link
 {mso-style-name:social-link;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.contact-item, li.contact-item, div.contact-item
 {mso-style-name:contact-item;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.alert, li.alert, div.alert
 {mso-style-name:alert;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.alert-warning, li.alert-warning, div.alert-warning
 {mso-style-name:alert-warning;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 background:lemonchiffon;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.text-left, li.text-left, div.text-left
 {mso-style-name:text-left;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.text-right, li.text-right, div.text-right
 {mso-style-name:text-right;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 text-align:right;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.mj-carousel-icons-cell, li.mj-carousel-icons-cell, div.mj-carousel-icons-cell
 {mso-style-name:mj-carousel-icons-cell;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
p.mj-carousel-radio, li.mj-carousel-radio, div.mj-carousel-radio
 {mso-style-name:mj-carousel-radio;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;
 display:none;}
p.mj-carousel-next, li.mj-carousel-next, div.mj-carousel-next
 {mso-style-name:mj-carousel-next;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;
 display:none;}
p.mj-carousel-previous, li.mj-carousel-previous, div.mj-carousel-previous
 {mso-style-name:mj-carousel-previous;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;
 display:none;}
p.mj-carousel-thumbnail, li.mj-carousel-thumbnail, div.mj-carousel-thumbnail
 {mso-style-name:mj-carousel-thumbnail;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 margin-top:9.75pt;
 margin-right:0cm;
 margin-bottom:9.75pt;
 margin-left:0cm;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;}
span.hero-text
 {mso-style-name:hero-text;}
span.E-MailFormatvorlage35
 {mso-style-type:personal;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 color:#1F497D;}
span.E-MailFormatvorlage36
 {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
 {mso-style-type:export-only;
 font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
 {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
 margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 2.0cm 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
 {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="DE" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:18.0pt 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:-2.25pt;margin-right:-2.25pt">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100" style="width:75.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal"><a href="https://www.autoscout24.ch/de?utm_source=as24-systemmail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_term=header&amp;utm_content=de&amp;utm_campaign=SellerContact" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration:none"><img border="0" width="100" style="width:1.0416in" id="_x0000_i1025" src="https://www.autoscout24.ch/MVC/Content/desktop/img/autoscout24-logo-og.png"></span></a><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 31.5pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:27.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><b><span style="font-size:18.0pt;font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#003468">AutoScout24 Kontaktanfrage<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 13.5pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Guten Tag<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:4.5pt 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Ein Internetnutzer hat sich für Ihr Fahrzeug interessiert und das Kontaktformular ausgefüllt:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:1.0pt"><img border="0" width="400" style="width:4.1666in" id="_x0000_i1026" src="https://cas01.autoscout24.ch/bmw-x2-suv--gelaendewagen-2018-neu/?1024x2048/3/90/custom/549/5539549/0.jpg"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 9.0pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:22.5pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><b><span style="font-size:15.0pt;font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">BMW X2 xDrive 20d M Sport X Steptronic<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 9.0pt 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">schwarz mét., Neu, CHF 57'900.-, 10 km, EG03008<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:-2.25pt;margin-right:-2.25pt">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background:#FE8714;padding:7.5pt 15.0pt 7.5pt 15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:white"><a href="https://www.autoscout24.ch/5539549?utm_source=as24-systemmail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_term=vehicle&amp;utm_content=de&amp;utm_campaign=SellerContact" target="_blank"><span class="hero-text"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:white;background:#FE8714;text-decoration:none">Fahrzeug
 ansehen</span></span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 4.5pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:22.5pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><b><span style="font-size:15.0pt;font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Koordinaten des Interessenten:<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="35%" style="width:35.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;cellspacing:0px">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Name:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Julien F<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="35%" style="width:35.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Telefon:
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444"><a href="tel:&#43;41-791328706">&#43;41-791328706</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="35%" style="width:35.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">E-Mail:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444"><a href="mailto:julien.famaro@gmail.com">julien.famaro@gmail.com</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="35%" style="width:35.0%;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Sprache:<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Französisch<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 9.0pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:22.5pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><b><span style="font-size:15.0pt;font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Zusätzliche Fragen / Mitteilung:<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Grüezi,
<br>
Ich bin sehr interessiert. <br>
Können Sie mir eine Leasingofferte senden für 48 Monaten, 2000CHF Zahlung und 10'000km?
<br>
Fleet rabat: Amcor GmbH <br>
<br>
Vielen Dank, <br>
<br>
Freundliche Grüsse<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 18.0pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444"><a href="https://www.autoscout24.ch/de/misc/reportspam?srguid=1e86334c-43bb-46dc-9074-67f191197bc7">Spam und verdächtige
 Anfrage melden</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 31.5pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 4.5pt 3.75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:22.5pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><b><span style="font-size:15.0pt;font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Sicherheitshinweis<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;cellspacing:0px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;cellspacing:0px">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444">Achtung: Nicht alle Anfragen sind von vertrauenswürdigen Personen. Beachten Sie daher unbedingt den Ratgeber Autoverkauf
 sowie die Sicherheitshinweise, um bösen Überraschungen vorzubeugen. Diese Anfrage stammt aus folgendem Land: CH<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444"><a href="https://www.autoscout24.ch/de/c/c1/information/autoverkauf?c=1098&amp;utm_term=magazine&amp;utm_campaign=sellercontact&amp;utm_source=as24-systemmail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_term=ratgeber&amp;utm_content=de&amp;utm_campaign=SellerContact">Ratgeber
 Autoverkauf</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:18.0pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly"><span style="font-family:&quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;color:#444444"><a href="https://www.autoscout24.ch/de/c/d/information/sicherheitshinweise-von-autoscout24?a=1314&amp;utm_source=as24-systemmail&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_term=sicherheitshinweis&amp;utm_content=de&amp;utm_campaign=SellerContact">Sicherheitshinweis</a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:450.0pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;word-wrap:break-word">
<div>
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 0cm 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="590" valign="top" style="width:450.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 3.75pt 22.5pt 3.75pt">
<div align="center">
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse">
```